# Truncating leading zeros in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to represent the following records

```
DATA
000200AA
00000200AA
000020BCD
00000020BCD
000020ABC
```

AS

```
DATA    CNT
200AA   1
20BCD   2
20ABC   2
```

ANY IDEAS?

Comment: Are the leading zeros always followed by a `2` or are you always just interested in the right 5 characters?

Comment: they can be more than 5 as well o

Answer (score 8, accepted):

USE patindex

```
select count(test) as cnt,
 substring(test, patindex('%[^0]%',test),len(test)) from (

  select ('000200AA') as test
  union
  select '00000200AA' as test
  union
  select ('000020BCD') as test
  union
  select ('00000020BCD') as test
  union
  select ('000020ABC') as test

  )ty
 group by substring(test, patindex('%[^0]%',test),len(test))
```

Comment: Since the strings should be starting with `0`, do we still need the leading `%` (I'm not used to SQL Server, but the documentation seems to imply it's not necessary here...)?

Answer (score 3):

How about a nice recursive user-defined function?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StripLeadingZeros (
        @input varchar(MAX)
) RETURNS varchar(MAX)
BEGIN

    IF LEN(@input) = 0
        RETURN @input

    IF SUBSTRING(@input, 1, 1) = '0'
        RETURN dbo.StripLeadingZeros(SUBSTRING(@input, 2, LEN(@input) - 1))

    RETURN @input

END
GO
```

Then:

```
SELECT dbo.StripLeadingZeros(DATA) DATA, COUNT(DATA) CNT
FROM YourTable GROUP BY dbo.StripLeadingZeros(DATA)
```

Comment: Fun though that was, timus's solution is better. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(32) = N'000200AA'

SELECT  SUBSTRING ( @String ,CHARINDEX(N'2', @String),LEN(@String))
```

Comment: This only works if the first character will always be a `2`, which isn't something I would always count on.

Comment: looking at your example I thought the first character will always be a 2.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the what you need to get the values this code may differ:

Assuming a simple right 5 chars as Barry suggested, you can use RIGHT(data, 5) and GROUP BY and COUNT to get your results

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19ecd/2

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function

It inserts data into a string on a range

Answer (score 0):

You can do this query:

```
SELECT RIGHT([DATA],LEN[DATA])-PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',[DATA])+1) [DATA], COUNT(*) CNT
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY RIGHT([DATA],LEN[DATA])-PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',[DATA])+1)
```